# A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have used few Jqueries on my home page for sliding Images, Tabs and few more. They were working fine until I made few changes eg added new button and etc that have nothing to deal with my included Jqueries. And I included some images in my database for slider.. Now i am getting the following error.

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. 
You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: http://localhost/2011/js/sweet/jquery.min.js:4
```

Why i am getting an error of jquery.min.js and whats the last :4 in my error and How would i resolve it..

Comment: Can you show your changes? Or even better, the entire code?

Comment: You likely have an infinite loop somewhere in the jQuery code you have written. The :4 just means that the browser is getting stuck on line 4 of the minified jQuery library. But your code will be causing it.

Comment: its may have because of Firefox add-ons : "Ask Toolbar".

Comment: ...or if not an infinite loop a long-running loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the minified jquery.js with the full jquery.js, then see exactly where the error is occurring.  Use your favorite js debugger to set a breakpoint on that line, then observe the callstack.  You should be able to step back to your code, and see what is causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

To tell Firefox to let the script run longer:

In the Location bar, type `about:config` and press Enter.

The about:config *"This might void your warranty!"* warning page may appear. Click **I'll be careful, I promise!** to continue to the about:config page.

In the about:config page, search for the preference `dom.max_script_run_time`, and double-click on it.

In the *Enter integer value* prompt, type 20.

Press OK